# Web utility for viewing $x$-$t$, $v$-$t$, and $a$-$t$ graphs

Tags: kinematics, resource-recommendations, education, software, visualization

I'm wondering if there exists any utility on the web which displays $x$-$t$, $v$-$t$, and $a$-$t$ graphs for, say, a number of well considered example animations. The utility should allow pausing, rewinding, replaying, and 'stepping' through the animation. When playing the animation, it should 'highlight' the current time on the d,v, and a graphs.

Etc etc. I'm sure you have an idea what I'm after - searches online have mostly led me to lectures and lessons explaining the relationship between the three graphs.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/moving-man)?

Comment: That's certainly in the right ballpark, thanks! I'd like to find something though that contains a series of examples which are progressively difficult to mentally parse. And it would be nice if it were viewable natively in-browser across as many platforms as possible.

Comment: A particular difficulty with the above suggestion is that attempting to move the man with the mouse at a constant speed with results in an erratic acceleration graph - large positive and negative spikes. This will be counter-intuitive for students, and difficult to understand as an artifact of 'sampling'.

Comment: What about doing it yourself? Platform independent solution would be possible in Python. If at hand, Mathematica would make it simple. The CDF player is free and platform independent as well. Makes me wonder...did you have a look at the  Wolfram Demonstrations Project. There might be what you want and it should work with the CDF Player.