# Visualisation tool for different speeds?

Tags: kinematics, resource-recommendations, speed, software, visualization

I'm a student often doing kinematics word problems with objects moving at X km/h, Y m/s, or Z cm/s. Yet, I have no idea what these units look like in real life.

Out of curiosity, **I'm searching for a visualisation tool that lets me see how objects move at different speeds.** I'm hoping to find something like an animated car, ball, etc. with a slider that lets me adjust the speed it moves at. But real-life videos of real-life objects moving at different speeds would also work.

I also think that intuition is helpful when understanding the context of word problems + the answers you get.

Does anyone know of any such tools? I appreciate your help!

---

This is what I've looked at so far:

- [Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzcPl3rFxbY) that change video clip speeds to show cars moving at different speeds (though this is only for LARGE speeds in km/h.
- [Map tools](https://academo.org/demos/speed-of-light-visualizer/) that visualise the speed of light.
- [Software animations](https://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/0m6aj3vc/) that visualise rotation per minute speeds.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162209/2451

Comment: *I have no idea what these units look like in real life.* Why not? How fast do you walk? How slow does an ant crawl? How fast can a bicycle or motorcycle go? How fast does an airplane fly? Thinking in this way will be more useful than looking at a video or an animation.